# Finding and Comparing Homologous Genes

Tags: bioinformatics, phylogenetics

I have a gene of of interest that I would like to compare between homologues. How does one go about finding a gene from known coding sequences across phyla? Afterwards I imagine I could do a Clustal sequence alignment to see how the sequences match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various databases of homologs, for example:

- [eggNOG](http://eggnog.embl.de)
- Ensembl Compara (accessible via [BioMart](http://www.ensembl.org/biomart/martview), I think)
- [Homologene](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/homologene)
- [OMA](http://omabrowser.org/)
- [TreeFam](http://www.treefam.org/)

The advantage of using an existing database is that more sophisticated methods for detecting orthologs than simple BLAST searches have been used (see "[Computational methods for Gene Orthology inference](http://doi.org/cxwqpk)" for a review), and everything is already precomputed, so it's much faster. The downside is that all precomputed methods need to use a snapshot of the genomes from the past, so not all currently available genomes will be there.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question adequately, the [Genome Browser](http://genome.ucsc.edu) at UCSC is a great place to start. If you know the name of the gene, you can search for it. For example, [here is the page for human insulin receptor 1](http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?position=chr2:227659726-227663454&hgsid=265444947&knownGene=pack&hgFind.matches=uc021vxn.1,). From there you can compare 46 genomes, with alignments.

Comment: Wow that is an ugly interface. How do I use that thing? I think that's what I'm looking for. Looking at the INS-R1 gene as an example, I see chicken, zebrafish, a cluster of 46 vertebrates. Can I use this tool to create a consensus sequence of the conserved regions?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have any idea where your gene will have a match with other genes, try something like [Blast at the NCBI website](http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi).

This will give you a list of hits that you can then use to align with a multiple sequence aligner (MSA). The same NCBI page can give you a tree reconstructed from the results of the searching process, although there is a variety of methods that can be used if you just download the sequences and attempt to build the gene family alignment yourself using "[x] Select All -- Get selected sequences" in the NCBI blast results page, then downloading them in FASTA or other format with "Send to -- File -- Format FASTA -- Create File".

If what you want instead is to include your gene sequence into the best aligning place in an existing gene family alignment, you can try [PAGAN](http://code.google.com/p/pagan-msa/wiki/PAGAN).

Answer (score 4):

maybe you'd like NCBI/Homologene instead.  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/homologene

or just using psiblast against NR if you have a nucleotide or protein sequence.

http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi

Answer (score 2):

Just adding my 5 cents, there is a recent database called [metaphors](http://orthology.phylomedb.org/):

> MetaPhOrs is a public repository of phylogeny-based orthology and
>   paralogy predictions that were computed using resources available in
>   seven popular homology prediction services (PhylomeDB, EnsemblCompara,
>   EggNOG, OrthoMCL, COG, Fungal Orthogroups, and TreeFam). Currently
>   above 306 millions of unique homologous protein pairs are deposited in
>   MetaPhOrs database. These predictions were retrieved from 705 123
>   phylogenetic trees for 829 genomes. For each prediction, MetaPhOrs
>   provides a Consistency Score and Evidence Level describing its
>   goodness, together with number of trees and links to their source
>   databases.

It is particularly good because:

- It is the only homology database I know of that gives information on paralogy vs orthology.
- It is linked to UniProt names
- It provides a pretty good python API for batch queries